# iOS Speech Recognition or Speech To Text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, speech-recognition

I am testing out the Speech recognition API from Apple itself based on the sample code given by Apple in the Scrumdinger app.

The link for the scrumdinger app is here:
https://github.com/ahmaddorra/Scrumdinger

Based on this particular page MeetingView.swift https://github.com/ahmaddorra/Scrumdinger/blob/main/Scrumdinger/MeetingView.swift

I have worked out a simple test app just to test Speech Recognition but somehow I did not manage to make it work.  I speak to the phone after pressing the start button but in

> print(speechRecognizer.transcript)

No text was printed out.

Would appreciate if anyone could help to take a look at my implementation to see what I have missed out.

In the code below, the transcript was not printed out.

The whole github link for the iOS test app is here:
https://github.com/somaria/scrumtranscript

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State var textValue: String = "The transcription text"
  @StateObject var speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer()
  
  private var player: AVPlayer { AVPlayer.sharedDingPlayer }
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "mic")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
          Text(textValue)
          HStack(spacing: 64) {
            Button {
            
              print("starting")
              self.textValue = "New Text"
              
              player.seek(to: .zero)
              player.play()

              speechRecognizer.reset()
              speechRecognizer.transcribe()

            } label: {
              Text("Start")
            }
            Button {
              print("Stop")
              
              speechRecognizer.stopTranscribing()
              print(speechRecognizer.transcript)
            } label: {
              Text("Stopping")
            }

          }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. The code for a minimal example should be in the question not a link. Also, you haven't specified what isn't working.

Comment: @loremipsum I have uploaded the whole app to github:  https://github.com/somaria/scrumtranscript. The main stuff is in contentview.

Comment: Links break over time and aren't searchable on SO. They don't help the people that come to the website after you. Like I said in the first comment it should be included as code not a link and you still haven't specified what isn't working.